# Matching String to one of many RegEx patterns

Tags: regex, vb.net, dataset

I have a global DataSet called ds_SortPlan that I am using to map strings that match a certain regex pattern to an integer.

```
Private Function MatchDestination(ByVal code As String) As Integer
    Dim m As Match
    For Each tempRow As Data.DataRow In ds_SortPlan.Tables("MatchCode_Lookup").Rows
        m = Regex.Match(code, tempRow.Item("Match_String"))
        If m.Success Then
            Return tempRow.Item("ID")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next tempRow
    Return 0
End Function
```

This seem like a very slow and clunky way of doing this. :(
Is there a better way to set up a regex that will take a String code and try to match it against multiple patterns returning an associated ID number.

I would like to keep the DataSet if at all possible since there are lots of dependencies on it.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling this function often, you could store the patterns and reuse them, instead of reading them from the DB each time

```
Private Function MatchDestination(ByVal input As String) As Integer
    Static patterns As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

    If patterns Is Nothing Then
        patterns = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
        For Each row As DataRow In ds_SortPlan.Tables("MatchCode_Lookup").Rows
            Dim entry = New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)( _
                DirectCast(row.Item("ID"), Integer), _
                DirectCast(row.Item("Match_String"), String) _
            )
            patterns.Add(entry)
        Next
    End If

    For Each pattern As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In patterns
        If Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern.Value) Then
            Return pattern.Key
        End If
    Next
    Return 0
End Function
```

Note: You don't need `Exit Function` after `Return`. `Return` replaces the old `Exit Function` from VB6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make this method any faster without reconsidering your object model, but you can write it shorter (and more readable in my opinion):

```
Private Function MatchDestination(ByVal code As String) As Integer
    For Each row In ds_SortPlan.Tables("MatchCode_Lookup").Rows
        If Regex.Match(code, row.Item("Match_String")).Success Then
            Return row.Item("ID")
        End If
    Next row
    Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: yea, I thought I was asking for too much :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a caching there. Create a static array for regex and use old regex object from there instead of creating them again each time.
Also don't forget to compile regex if you are going to use them a lot. This will give you more performance when using for second or more time. So caching + compiling regex will give you performance boost; but it will make it slow for first run. Just add a RegexOptions.Compiled to arguments when creating a new regex.